# How to replace NaN values for image data?

Tags: python, machine-learning

My data set has a total of 200 columns, where each column corresponds to the same pixel in all of my images. In total, I have 48,500 rows. The labels for the data range from 0-9.

The data looks something like this:

```
    raw_0   raw_1   raw_2   raw_3   raw_4
0   120.0   133.0   96.0    155.0   66.0
1   159.0   167.0   163.0   185.0   160.0
2   45.0    239.0   66.0    252.0   NaN
3   126.0   239.0   137.0   NaN 120.0
4   226.0   222.0   153.0   235.0   171.0
5   169.0   81.0    100.0   44.0    104.0
6   154.0   145.0   76.0    134.0   175.0
7   77.0    35.0    105.0   108.0   112.0
8   104.0   55.0    113.0   90.0    107.0
9   97.0    253.0   255.0   251.0   141.0
10  224.0   227.0   84.0    214.0   57.0
11  NaN 13.0    51.0    50.0    NaN
12  82.0    213.0   61.0    98.0    59.0
13  NaN 40.0    84.0    7.0 39.0
14  129.0   103.0   65.0    159.0   NaN
15  123.0   128.0   116.0   198.0   111.0
```

Each column has around 5% missing values and I want to fill in these NaN
values with something meaningful. However, I'm not sure how to go about this. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Common approaches are

- removing the row altogether
- setting the missing value to the mean/median of all the column, or of the entries belonging to the same class.

Comment: I know how to replace the values, what I'm interested in is finding meaningful values to replace them with.